# EXCEL, use comma instead of dot in numbers generated from xml

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

I am generating numbers from XML file, that is refreshing every X time. And I need to have the output in numbers separated with commas, not with dots, like it is in the XML, because I cant work (multiply etc) with numbers separated with dot.

My XML output looks like:

*Number One   N1   14.5*

*Number Two   N2   578.4*

But I need to have it like:

*Number One   N1   14,5*

*Number Two   N2   578,4*

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I tried ti separate it with =SPLIT, or get the value by =VALUE, but it did not work. I just need to change the . for , in the number format.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other commas in the file?
Otherwise you can just use the find and replace tool.

Ctrl+F -> replace tab -> find "." replace with ",".

If you need it for a macro, you can just record yourself doing that, and you'll end up with something similar to

```
    Cells.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Do you need something more advanced?

Comment: I tried to change it with replace tool, but the problem is that the output is refreshing every one minute. I need it for actula currency rate. I am getting actual values from XML file, but the output is with dots. I actualy tried some plugins for that, but even the plugins have the output with dots or do not include my currency.

I am beginner in excel, never worked with macros.

Comment: @Kulda If you go into the developer tab – [if you can't see the developer tab in excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#_ShowDeveloperTab) – and go into visual basic.
Doubleclick the sheet in question, and on the top right where it says "(general)" select worksheet.
If you in the right menu select, say, "SelectionChange", it will create a private sub. Paste the code into that sub. 
Now the sheet will run the code, and change all "." to "," every time a cell is selected in the sheet.